# Objekte stehen immer im Akkusativ; nicht im Genitiv oder Dativ?

Tags: sentence-structure, accusative, objects

Wenn man Texte einiger Linguisten liest, wird immer wieder erwähnt, dass gemäß der traditionellen Linguistik Objekte immer im Akkusativ stehen. Genitiv- und Dativobjekte seien Erfindungen der modernen Germanistik. Aus dem Lateinunterricht erinnere ich mich noch wage daran, dass Dative und Genitive eben nicht als Objekte sondern gemäß ihrer Funktion bezeichnet wurden, bspw. als Dativus possessivus. Nun probierte ich im Internet noch etwas genauer diesbezüglich zu recherchieren, doch alle Suchmaschienen spucken nur Grundschularbeitsblätter zum Satzbau aus. Nun frage ich mich ob hier jemand eine Resource kennt, auf der ich so etwas nachlesen könnte.

Comment: Also benutzen einige Linguisten eine andere (engere) Definition des Begriffs "Objekt" als andere. An der deutschen Sprache ändert sich dadurch nichts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So etwas in der Art habe ich auch des öfteren gelesen, allerdings nicht derart in Erinnerung wie es oben beschrieben wurde.

Das betrifft [Akkusativsprachen](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkusativsprache). Darunter wird auch Deutsch gezählt.

Wie es sich im Lateinischen verhielte, und wie das mit Akkusativsprachen in Zusammenhang steht, dürfte hier zu weit führen.

Comment: Vielen Dank, der Begriff "Akkusativsprache" hat ich bei meiner Recherche weitergebracht!

Answer (score 0):

Ein Objekt im Deutschen kann im Akkusativ, Dativ oder Genitiv stehen - es ist trotzdem ein Objekt.

Ein Objekt kann auch *in gar keinem offensichtlichen Fall stehen*, z.B. weil es durch einen Nebensatz dargestellt wird.

> Sie sieht nicht, wer da kommt

Prädikative wie in

> Mein Vater ist Arzt

werden/wurden auch hin und wieder ganz gerne als Nominativobjekte bezeichnet (das hat sich aber nicht durchgesetzt)

Die von dir erwähnte These, dass es nur Akkusativobjekte gäbe, habe ich zumindestens für das Deutsche noch nie gehört.

Comment: Die moderne Schulgrammatik, der Duden und auch die amtliche Rechtschreibung verwenden die Begriffe "Dativobjekt" und "Genitivobjekt", es hat ja auch seine Gründe. Betrachtet man aber die historische Entwicklung des Deutschen, ist es sinnvoll, sich der Funktion der Worte im Satz bewusst zu werden. Aus diesem Grund verwenden alle historischen Linguisten diese Begriffe nicht, sondern eben bspw. Dativus commodi. Es verhält sich ähnlich mit dem "Genus Verbi" ein Begriff, der ursprünglich von Schulgrammatiken eingeführt wurde, um ein Pendant zum Genus des Nomens zu haben. Eigentlich hieß es Diathese

Comment: Den Begriff der Akkusativsprache kannte ich - aber nicht in einem Kontext, wie du ihn in deiner Frage beschrieben hast - Sondern in dem Kontext, *was markiert wird* - und das ist im Deutschen eben nicht der Nominativ.